# Python Kernel Died when using triple for loop containing requires_grad=True parameters (Pytorch)

Tags: python, kernel, spyder, pytorch

I just want to store `para_k` in every position of `COV` matrix, where:

```
para_k=torch.tensor([2.0],requires_grad=True).
```

And because I want to update parameters by optimising a loss function later(omitted here), I have to add another for loop. Therefore, the whole code is as follows:

```
import torch
para_k=torch.tensor([2.0],requires_grad=True)
for t in range(5):
    num_row=300
    num_col=300
    COV = torch.zeros((num_row,num_col))
    for i in range(num_row):
        for j in range(num_col):
            COV[i,j]=para_k
            print('i= %d ,j= %d' % (i,j) )
```

This simple computation cannot be finished by Spyder!!
Things can go well if I change `nrow` and `ncol` to be smaller than 100.
If I use number larger than 100, it will send error message (sometimes even one iteration cannot be finished) that Kernel died and restarting: Spyder Kernel Died

[image: Spyder Kernel Died]

I even uninstall and install again my Anaconda and reinstall pytorch. I also tried to run Spyder as administrator, still got the error.
I check the event of my system, the  error is: ntdll.dll regarding to pythonw.exe. I listed pythonw.exe as exception of firewall, but still cannot solve the problem.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you able to run this code in the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba No, Jupyter sent the same error (Kernel Died) in a message box.

Comment: Then the problem is not with Spyder or Jupyter, but with your code. I'd say it's a memory problem, i.e. your computer is left out of RAM when running your code and that's what makes the kernel die.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, i think I figure it out. it is not the problem about Spyder or Jupyter. I think it's because I use 'torch.zeros((num_row,num_col))' in the for loop. Maybe this sounds strange, but sometimes I run torch.zeros to create a variable it will go wrong. To solve this, I use something else rather than for loop and only use torch.zeros outside iteration ( never use torch.zeros inside iterations).

Comment: Great!! Glad you figured this one out.